# error with @ifnextchar and paralist after texlive 2014 update

Tags: environments, parameters, paralist

I've been using a save/restore `TeX`nique with `let/def` to redefine the `\@enumerate@` command from the [*paralist*](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) package so that the `enumerate` environment can accept a second optional parameter (a name of an automatically created `newcommand` - to be employed in generating `\label`s for `\item`s for later `\ref`erences).

Here is an MWE to illustrate the problem.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[alwaysadjust,newitem,newenum]{paralist}
\usepackage{suffix,xkeyval,xargs,xifthen}

\makeatletter
\let\mwe@enumerate@\@enumerate@
\def\@enumerate@{\@ifnextchar[{\mwe@enum*{enumerate}[}%
                              {\mwe@enum{enumerate}}}

\newcommandx\mwe@enum[3][2,3=mwe@]{\csname#3#1@\endcsname}
%\newcommandx\mwe@enum[3][2,3=mwe@]{\@nameuse{#3#1@}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\mwe@enum*[2][2]{\mwe@enum{#1}[\@gobble#2]}

\def\mwe{\@ifnextchar[{\mw@*{k}[}{\mw@{w}}}
\newcommandx\mw@[2][2=q]{#1 / #2\\}
\WithSuffix\newcommandx\mw@*[2][2]{\mw@{#1}[\@gobble#2]}

\makeatother

\title{MWE}
\author{tex.stackexchange.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent\mwe\mwe[x]

\iftrue
\begin{enumerate}[(1)][here]
\item test\label{here:1} % this would be auto-generated
\end{enumerate}
\fi

% further it would be possible to issue \here[1] instead of \ref{here:1}

\end{document}
```

The starred `\mwe@enum*` is an indirect call to the unstarred `\mwe@enum`, passing it the second `\@gobble`'d argument.

While `\@ifnextchar` works well together with `\@gobble` for the `\mwe` verifying command, for the `enumerate` environment in [*paralist*](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), the second argument in square brackets ("here") if present gives errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   h
l.41     \item
               test
? h
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I have updated texlive to 2014 early this month. Before, everything worked well with my code. It seems [*paralist*](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) upgraded between 2013 and 2014 too, from

```
          [2002/03/18 v2.3b Extended list environments (BS)]
```

to

```
          [2013/06/09 v2.4 Extended list environments]
```

but the difference seems to be only the type of error (2002):

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 \item t
            est
? h
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

There is an alternative package [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), but in this case should remain an alternative for the user.

Appreciate any support.

Thank s.

Comment: I get the “lonely item” error with `paralist` version 2.3b (under TeX Live 2010, 2011 and 2012). So there's apparently nothing to fix: the code has always been wrong.

Comment: Also `\mwe@enum*` is never reached and you never use `\mwe@enumerate@`, so the "lonely item” problem is obvious. It would be useful to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thank s. for your answer: this was it, `\mwe@enum*` was never reached... The `[` is consumed in `paralist`'s `\@enumwidestlabel@` (as I was able to `\typeout`). I am not *trying* to achieve something, since I worked and finished it already :).

Comment: I was able to `diff` texlive 2013 vs 2014, and they've updated independently `paralist.sty`, introducing `\@enumwidestlabel@`, that is invoked just after the second `[` is possibly absorbed, thus saving me from doing `\@ifnexchar[` once, but compelling me to override it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\@enumerate@` command is executed when the first optional argument has already been absorbed. You want to patch `\enumerate`, instead:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[alwaysadjust,newitem,newenum]{paralist}

\makeatletter
\let\mwe@enumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\mwe@enumerate@aux}{\mwe@enumerate}%
}
\def\mwe@enumerate@aux[#1]{%
  \mwe@enumerate[#1]%
  \@ifnextchar[\mwe@getnext{}%
}
\def\mwe@getnext[#1]{%
  % probably something more useful will be here
  \typeout{***The second optional argument is #1***}%
}
\makeatother

\title{MWE}
\author{tex.stackexchange.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}[(1)][here]
\item test\label{here:1} % this would be auto-generated
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The same with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\savedenumerate\enumerate

\RenewDocumentCommand{\enumerate}{ o o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\savedenumerate}
   {%
    \savedenumerate[#1]\IfValueT{#2}{\dosomething{#2}}
   }%
 }

\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \typeout{***The second optional argument is #1***}%
}
```

Comment: What can I say? `xparse` would probably make me rewrite the entire code (not just this particular case of enumerate-family environments), whereas patching `\enumerate` tempted me from the very first, but a reason that I stuck with `paralist` is that it allows me to redefine `\@enumerate@` et al. - which work in the "background".

Comment: I will not answer my own question - I use the `ifthenx.sty`/`\isnumber` test to either take [#2] as a size hint or as mwe's label (non-number) name, in the patched `\@enumwidestlabel@` - since your two solutions are actual and valid.